# using javascript i am displaying check boxes with some lists

Tags: javascript

I am printing list of arrays using checkboxes, the scenario is if I click one checkbox it display a list of numbers in the array, so my problem is if I click any checkbox it is displaying if I uncheck list is still in the display? so I want the code for, if I uncheck my list should go and when I click it should display.

```js
 var men=[1,2,5,4,8,1,5];
    var women=[45,55,45];
    var children=[256,365];
    document.getElementById("checkbox1").onchange=function(){
        for(i=0; i<men.length; i++){
            document.getElementById("userlist").innerHTML+= "<li>" + men[i] + "</li>";
            document.getElementById("checkbox1").onchange='';
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("checkbox2").onchange=function(){
        for(i=0; i<women.length; i++){
            document.getElementById("userlist").innerHTML+= "<li>" + women[i] + "</li>";
            document.getElementById("checkbox2").onchange='';
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("checkbox3").onchange=function(){
        document.getElementById("checkbox3").onchange='';
        for(i=0; i<children.length; i++){
            document.getElementById("userlist").innerHTML+= "<li>" + children[i] + "</li>";
           
           
        } 
    }
```

```html
 <label for="checkbox1">men</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
   <label for="checkbox2">women</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">
   <label for="checkbox3">children</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id ="checkbox3">
   <ul id="userlist">

   </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to add all `<li>` on load and just hide/show on checkbox click.

```js
var men = [1, 2, 5, 4, 8, 1, 5];
var women = [45, 55, 45];
var children = [256, 365];

//Adding all the elements with style display:none
for (i = 0; i < men.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById("userlist").innerHTML += "<li class='li-men' style='display:none'>" + men[i] + "</li>";
}

for (i = 0; i < women.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById("userlist").innerHTML += "<li class='li-women' style='display:none'>" + women[i] + "</li>";
}

for (i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById("userlist").innerHTML += "<li class='li-children' style='display:none'>" + children[i] + "</li>";
}


document.getElementById("checkbox1").onchange = function() {
  var li = document.getElementsByClassName('li-men');
  for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById('checkbox1').checked) {
      li[i].style.display = '';
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById("checkbox2").onchange = function() {
  var li = document.getElementsByClassName('li-women');
  for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById('checkbox2').checked) {
      li[i].style.display = '';
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
document.getElementById("checkbox3").onchange = function() {
  var li = document.getElementsByClassName('li-children');
  for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById('checkbox3').checked) {
      li[i].style.display = '';
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="checkbox1">men</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
<label for="checkbox2">women</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">
<label for="checkbox3">children</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3">
<ul id="userlist">

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are removing `onchange` event from the element once shown all li's and not hiding them instead, see the update below

```js
var men = [1, 2, 5, 4, 8, 1, 5];
var women = [45, 55, 45];
var children = [256, 365];
document.getElementById("checkbox1").onchange = function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    for (i = 0; i < men.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById("userlist").innerHTML += "<li>" + men[i] + "</li>";
      //document.getElementById("checkbox1").onchange='';
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("userlist").innerHTML = '';
  }
}
document.getElementById("checkbox2").onchange = function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    for (i = 0; i < women.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById("userlist").innerHTML += "<li>" + women[i] + "</li>";
      //document.getElementById("checkbox2").onchange='';
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("userlist").innerHTML = '';
  }
}
document.getElementById("checkbox3").onchange = function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    for (i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById("userlist").innerHTML += "<li>" + children[i] + "</li>";

    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("userlist").innerHTML = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="checkbox1">men</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
<label for="checkbox2">women</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">
<label for="checkbox3">children</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3">
<ul id="userlist">

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can minimise and make your code generic in addition to showing and hiding the array values. You can associate a `onclick` function to each checkbox and pass parameters to those function like `type` which specifies the array that should be shown and checkbox reference so that you can manipulate this checkbox in javascript code:

```js
var men=[1,2,5,4,8,1,5];
var women=[45,55,45];
var children=[256,365];
function clickCb(type, cbElem){
  var targetArray;
  if(type === 'men'){
    targetArray = men;
  }
  if(type === 'women'){
    targetArray = women;
  }
  if(type === 'children'){
    targetArray = children;
  }
  if (cbElem.checked) {
    for (i = 0; i < targetArray.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById("userlist").innerHTML += "<li>" + targetArray[i] + "</li>";
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("userlist").innerHTML = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="checkbox1">men</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" onclick = clickCb('men',this)>
<label for="checkbox2">women</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" onclick = clickCb('women',this)>
<label for="checkbox3">children</label>
<input type="checkbox" id ="checkbox3" onclick = clickCb('children',this)>
<ul id="userlist">

</ul>
```